# Show popover at page refresh

Tags: bootstrap-4, popover

I want to show all popovers from page by default at page refresh/initialize.
I use bootstrap for popover.

Jquery:

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

Html:

```html
<button data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="" data-placement="bottom"></button>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are supposed to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply give an argument `'show'` when call `popover()`

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show')
```

Working snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show')
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Pop">Popover</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Pop">Popover</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Pop">Popover</button>
```